# Custom Authentication Entrypoint not being called on failed Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have setup an OAUTH Authorization server that's supposed to allow clients request for tokens. It's also supposed to allow admin users carry out other operations.

In my Web Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private @Autowired CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private @Autowired CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(entryPoint, new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/**"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Ideally, when an admin user tries to call any endpoint under "/api/v1/**", they should be authenticated - and in fact, they are.

The issue now is, when authentication fails, the authentication entry endpoint is ignored. I don't understand why this is.

I even included the "default authentication entry point for" just to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Please, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the http security configuration, I took inspiration from this article (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication) and changed it to:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
     }
```

Honestly, I don't know why what I had before wasn't working. Plenty of people have posted that as the solution to problems about entry end points. But I guess maybe something has changed in Spring that I'm not aware of.